# DIY plumbing change - am i to code?

Tags: plumbing

Please see attached diagram of my new plumbing setup plan.
Will there be any code issues or problems with this?

im referencing the 2014 Florida plumbing code (IPC)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't have access to the Florida Plumbing Code or the International Plumbing Code. I do have knowledge of the Canadian National Plumbing Code:

What you have is two groups of fixtures, both being vented via wet vents. One of the rules of wet venting is that the toilet needs to be the last fixture connected.

The second floor group passes this requirement but the downstairs group does not. The correction is simple: instead of using the two 3x3x2 wye & 45 combos, use a single double 3x3x2 wye & 45 combo fitting to connect both the sink and the shower to the 3" pipe.

[image]

This provides a symmetrical connection of all three fixtures and resolves the issue.

The intent of this rule is that when the toilet is flushed, it has the potential to choke off the wet vent portion serving the shower.